# Memory Leak Error when deploying clojure ring application on tomcat 8

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, memory-leaks, clojure, korma

I'm trying to deploy a ring app war on tomcat 8. Created war with `lein ring uberwar`.

I suspect it is because of jdbc connection thread but not sure.

I'm using 
`[org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1206-jdbc42"]` and `[korma "0.4.1"]`

project.clj

```
  :ring {:handler hello-world.handler/app
         :init    hello-world.handler/init
         :destroy hello-world.handler/destroy}
```

handler.clj

```
(korma.db/defdb db (korma.db/postgres {:db "hello_world"
                                       :user "user"
                                       :password "password"
                                       :host "localhost"}))

(defn init []
  (println "Init..."))

(defn destroy []
  (-> (korma.db/connection-pool db) :datasource .close))
```

---

Here's the error trace from tomcat logs -

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/hello-world-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.war
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/hello-world-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone] startup failed due to previous errors
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/hello-world-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone] appears to have started a thread named [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/hello-world-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone] appears to have started a thread named [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/hello-world-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [clojure.lang.Var$1] (value [clojure.lang.Var$1@3a2ddd4f]) and a value of type [clojure.lang.Var.Frame] (value [clojure.lang.Var$Frame@191c8b60]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/hello-world-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [clojure.lang.Var$1] (value [clojure.lang.Var$1@3a2ddd4f]) and a value of type [clojure.lang.Var.Frame] (value [clojure.lang.Var$Frame@21025881]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Comment: Is it complete code that recreates the issue? Or you omitted some code that could potentially use thread locals (e.g. by using dynamic vars)?

Comment: I haven't used dynamic vars, refs, atoms etc. And yes, there are some routes and db queries code I omitted. But I guess those queries and controller actions won't create such issues.

Comment: Also I've pasted the error trace of tomcat 7 but the same trace appeared in tomcat 8. No difference.

Comment: You can grab a heap dump after redeploying your application and check what are the GC roots to that `var` and value it holds. It might answer your question who is the culprit.

Comment: heap dump is not able to catch those `var`. Before they can even reach to heap dump, tomcat terminates the deployment with this exception. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can take a heap dump before you undeploy your application and then you can inspect the dump for the instances reported in Tomcat logs.